# Inserting li element into ul of a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, insert, html-lists

I would like to use JavaScript to insert a new li element into an existing ul. The new li element would be the last item in the ul.

```
<div id="foo">
   <div>
     <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       ....insert html here....
     </ul>    
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be as easy as

```
var ul = document.querySelector('#foo ul');
var li = document.createElement('li');

li.innerHTML = 'new LI';
li.className = 'someclass';

ul.appendChild(li);
```

or in jQuery

```
$('#foo ul').append( $('<li />', {text : 'new LI'}) );
```

Comment: Thanks but forgot to add in my original post that the li elements all have classes. How would I add the class attribute when adding the new li element?

Comment: @DM - you'd just modify the `className` property, like above

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is there a way to add the class using jQuery as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try ".append()"

```js
$('#foo ul').append( '<li />' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
   <div>
     <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       ....insert html here....
     </ul>    
   </div>
</div>
```